# Neo4 Hierarchy Traversal

Tags: neo4j

I've got some hierarchical data stored in neo4j and need a query to find all children of a parent node for a particular user. The basic scenario is:

```
(Root Task {control: 1})
    (Child Task 2 {control: 2})
    (Child Task 3 {control: 3})
        (Child Task 4 {control: 4})
```

The child tasks have a `:CHILD_OF` relationship to the parent. So this is all fine, and I'm able to get the children of a parent. Using the following query I would get Child Task 4 returned.

```
MATCH (rootTask:Task {control: 3}), (user:User {control: 60})
,(childTask:Task)-[:CHILD_OF*]->(rootTask)
WHERE (user)-[:LINKED_TO]->(childTask)
RETURN childTask
```

The problem comes in with the need for a user to re-arrange the structure, but only for himself. So I introduced a new relationship, which contains a reference to the user. `CHILD_OF_<usercontrol>` is added and if it exists it should take preference over the `CHILD_OF` relationship.

So if user 60 decides the (Child Task 4) task should fall under the (Root Task) and not (Child Task 3), there are two links created:

```
MERGE (Level 4 task)-[:CHILD_OF]->(Child Task 3)
MERGE (Level 4 task)-[:CHILD_OF_60]->(Root Task)
```

His view is now basically:

```
(Root Task {control: 1})
    (Child Task 2 {control: 2})
    (Child Task 3 {control: 3})
    (Child Task 4 {control: 4})
```

So now when I ask for children of (Child Task 3), for user 60 I don't want (Child Task 4) returned.

Using the previous query and adding the user specific relationship and an additional constraint to not return a child task if it has a user specific link to an unbound task almost works, expect it will return children of (Child Task 4) because they only have a CHILD_OF relationship that gets linked to. The logic to exclude childTask's that have a user specific link is also flawed because it might actually point to the same parent.

```
MATCH (rootTask:Task {control: 3}), (user:User {control: 60})
,(childTask:Task)-[:CHILD_OF|CHILD_OF_60*]->(rootTask)
WHERE (user)-[:LINKED_TO]->(childTask) 
AND NOT (childTask)-[:CHILD_OF_60]-(:Task)
RETURN childTask
```

The essence of the logic I need is just if relationship CHILD_OF_60 exists for a task follow that relationship and ignore the default CHILD_OF relationship.

---

### Test data

```
MERGE (ruan :User {control: 50, fullname: 'Ruan'})
MERGE (amber :User {control: 60, fullname: 'Amber'})
MERGE (task1 :Task {control: 1, subject: 'Root Task:'})
MERGE (task2 :Task {control: 2, subject: 'Child of Root:'})
MERGE (task3 :Task {control: 3, subject: 'User properties'})
MERGE (task4 :Task {control: 4, subject: 'User parent links'})
MERGE (task5 :Task {control: 5, subject: 'Hierarchy Traversal'})
MERGE (task6 :Task {control: 6, subject: 'Parent'})
MERGE (task7 :Task {control: 7, subject: 'Child'})
MERGE (task8 :Task {control: 8, subject: 'Query1'})
MERGE (task2)-[:CHILD_OF]->(task1)
MERGE (task3)-[:CHILD_OF]->(task2)
MERGE (task4)-[:CHILD_OF]->(task2)
MERGE (task5)-[:CHILD_OF]->(task2)
MERGE (task6)-[:CHILD_OF]->(task5)
MERGE (task7)-[:CHILD_OF]->(task5)
MERGE (task8)-[:CHILD_OF]->(task7)
MERGE (ruan)-[:LINKED_TO]->(task1)
MERGE (ruan)-[:LINKED_TO]->(task2)
MERGE (ruan)-[:LINKED_TO]->(task3)
MERGE (ruan)-[:LINKED_TO]->(task4)
MERGE (ruan)-[:LINKED_TO]->(task5)
MERGE (ruan)-[:LINKED_TO]->(task6)
MERGE (ruan)-[:LINKED_TO]->(task7)
MERGE (ruan)-[:LINKED_TO]->(task8)
MERGE (amber)-[:LINKED_TO]->(task1)
MERGE (amber)-[:LINKED_TO]->(task2)
MERGE (amber)-[:LINKED_TO]->(task3)
MERGE (amber)-[:LINKED_TO]->(task4)
MERGE (amber)-[:LINKED_TO]->(task5)
MERGE (amber)-[:LINKED_TO]->(task6)
MERGE (amber)-[:LINKED_TO]->(task7)
MERGE (amber)-[:LINKED_TO]->(task8)
MERGE (task2)-[:CHILD_OF]->(task1)
MERGE (task3)-[:CHILD_OF]->(task2)
MERGE (task4)-[:CHILD_OF]->(task2)
MERGE (task5)-[:CHILD_OF]->(task2)
MERGE (task6)-[:CHILD_OF]->(task5)
MERGE (task7)-[:CHILD_OF]->(task5)
MERGE (task8)-[:CHILD_OF]->(task7)
MERGE (task5)-[:CHILD_OF_60]->(task1)
MERGE (task3)-[:CHILD_OF_60]->(task1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a fun one to work on.  I've made up a GraphGist here to demonstrate my suggestion:

http://graphgist.neo4j.com/#!/gists/54d8b5ef8cfb85197aa4

But I'll put the solution here as well:

```
MATCH
  (rootTask:Task { control: 1 }),
  path=(childTask:Task)-[:CHILD_OF|CHILD_OF_60*1..]->rootTask,
  (user:User { control: 60 })-[:LINKED_TO]->childTask
WITH childTask, path AS the_path, path
UNWIND nodes(path) AS node
OPTIONAL MATCH node-[:CHILD_OF_60]->(otherParent:Task)
WITH childTask, the_path, collect(otherParent IS NULL OR otherParent IN nodes(the_path))[0..-1] AS otherParentResults
WHERE ALL(result IN otherParentResults WHERE result)
RETURN DISTINCT childTask
```

Basically I'm getting the path, checking to see if the leaf node has another parent via the `CHILD_OF_60` relationship, and then returning the child if it doesn't have another parent or if the otherParent isn't in the ancestry path.

I'd feel more comfortable with this solution if it were backed by automated tests, but give it a try! ;)

Also, as a rule I try not to make variable relationship names.  You may want to consider having an optional `user_id` property on your `CHILD_OF` relationships.  Alternatively you might have something like a `CHILD_OF_FOR_USER` relationship type which has a `user_id` property.

**EDIT: I've edited the query above and the GraphGist to take care of child nodes with moved ancestors in the path to the root node**

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks a lot for taking a look at this. The variable relationships concept didn't feel completely sensible, I'll definitely try your suggestion. I ran your query on my test data, the only problem still is that child tasks of a moved parent still appear. Running your query for rootTask control 2 doesn't show "Hierarchy Traversal", but does still show it's children. I have added my test data to the question if your up for it. I'll also try to extend your query from side.

Comment: Great, thanks.  I'll look later, but you also might try creating an example GraphGist based on mine.  See the source here: https://gist.github.com/cheerfulstoic/54d8b5ef8cfb85197aa4 .  You can try forking that and then replacing your gist's UUID in this URL to see the results: http://graphgist.neo4j.com/#!/gists/54d8b5ef8cfb85197aa4

Comment: Ok, give the new query a try.  I've also updated the GraphGist to show it covering various cases

Comment: Awesome! Seems to be doing the trick! I'll need to investigate a few components in your cypher query I haven't used before to understand what it's doing. But it looks good, thanks again, much appreciated!

Comment: Yeah, I had a bit of trouble keeping my mind wrapped around the query at times myself ;)